# How to create contextmenu to delete row for inside of qtableview python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, contextmenu, qtableview

below is the code i am using:
How to create contextmenu to delete row for inside of qtableview python.

It is showing menu even i clicked on Qpushbutton also but i need to show the delete menu on only inside of qtableview. and let me know the way to delete the row of qtableview data.
Please let me know the solution.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys
import sqlite3


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("tableview.ui", self)
        self.show()

        self.view_msa()

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.view_msa)

                
    def view_msa(self):
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

        conn = sqlite3.connect('book.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM card")
        db_data = cur.fetchall()
        print(db_data)
        for line in db_data:
            row = []
            for item in line:
                cell = QStandardItem(str(item))
                row.append(cell)

            self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Name","Age","Gender"])
            self.model.appendRow(row)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        self.click_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        renameAction = QtWidgets.QAction('Delete', self)
        renameAction.triggered.connect(lambda: self.renameSlot(event))
        self.click_menu.addAction(renameAction)

        self.click_menu.popup(QtGui.QCursor.pos())

    def renameSlot(self, event):
        print("Renameing slot called")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: If you only delete the row in the tableview, it won't be deleted in the source database, are you aware of this?

Comment: @musicamante. You are correct, the row deletion from the source database is different. I tried with _rowid_ of the table but it is not working properly I am facing a little bit difficulty. So can you show me the solution, is this cover with in this question or do i need to ask in next question?

Comment: I cannot add it, as it's completely unrelated to this question, but before creating a new question, I suggest you to do some research about using [QSqlDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html) and [QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html) (I suggest you to do some simple tests using basic code to understand how they work), which provide a direct interface to the database and will also allow you to use my code anyway. A hint: since you're using sqlite, open the database using `db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE'); db.setDatabaseName(<db file path>)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All widget have the [`contextMenuPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) property, which if set to `QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu` allows to connect to the [`customContextMenuRequested(pos)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal (note that the `pos` is in widget coordinates). From there you can access the index that is at the mouse position through [`indexAt`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#indexAt) or, better, get the selectedIndexes (which is useful if you have multiple selection enabled).

```
class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        # ...

        self.tableView.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.tableView.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.tableMenu)

    def tableMenu(self, pos):
        selected = self.tableView.selectedIndexes()
        if not selected:
            return
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        deleteAction = menu.addAction('Delete rows')
        deleteAction.triggered.connect(lambda: self.removeRows(selected))
        menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())

    def removeRows(self, indexes):
        # get unique row numbers
        rows = set(index.row() for index in indexes)
        # remove rows in *REVERSE* order!
        for row in sorted(rows, reverse=True):
            self.model.removeRow(row)
```

Note that in this case you have to use `menu.exec()` (which is usually the preferred method), not `popup()`, otherwise the function will return instantly and the menu won't probably shown up because of internal processing of the mouse events: `exec` blocks until it returns (whether any of its actions are triggered or it's closed), `popup` returns immediately.

Comment: Can you explain to me that why need revers order not normal order.    "for row in sorted(rows, reverse=True):"

Comment: It's the same as trying to remove items in a list. If you want to remove the first two items, you cannot do `del someList[0]; del someList[1];`: as soon as the first item is removed, the *previous* second item becomes the first, so if you try to remove item [1] you'll end up removing what was the *third* item. Using a reversed *sorted* order prevents that.